# How to run following command to test kafka server is installed properly or not?

Tags: java, command, apache-kafka, classpath

I have installed Kafka as well zookeeper. Zookeeper is working fine. However, when I try to run Kafka server, I get the below error. Please help me with a solution for this problem. Thank you in advance!!!

**Command run from C:\kafka-0.9.0.1 :**

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
```

**Error message:** 
*Classpath is empty. Please build the project first e.g. by running 'gradlew jarAll'*

Answer (score 13):

When you installed Kafka, did you download from a source download or a binary download? This problem occurs when you download a source distribution.

To fix this, download via the binary download link:

[Kafka 0.11.0.0 Binary](http://kafka.apache.org/downloads.html)

Also, the bat files for windows seem to have some problems, so I suggest following the guide here:

http://blog.anilot.tk/2014/08/06/Set-Up-Kafka-On-Windows/

Using the bat files from the Github repository linked in the guide.

Comment: any idea how to download the binary from confluent? I am interested to have kafka confluent (https://www.confluent.io/download) so that I can develop a consumer for a client which has schema registry - developed by confluent! I work in .NET but cannot start zookeeper from confluent.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not too sure how to go about that. Maybe opening a question on here, so someone with knowledge can help!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, modify <install_dir>\bin\windows\kafka-run-class.bat file and add these lines:

```sh
if exist "%BASE_DIR%\share\java\kafka\*" (
    call :concat "%BASE_DIR%\share\java\kafka\*"
)
```

before the line containing the text "rem Classpath addition for core".

Hopefully, it will fix the Classpath related issue.