# Issue on set up Kafka environment

Tags: batch-file, gradle, apache-kafka, classpath, apache-zookeeper

Currently, I am having an issue on installing and configuring a Kafka environment. There's no issue on downloading zookeeper, and the server works fine. Unfortunately, the error that I got when execute kafka-server-start.bat is:

**Classpath is empty. Please build the project first e.g. by running 'gradlew jarAll'**

Can someone please help?
By the way, I'm using the below docs for installation reference:
[Running Apache Kafka on windows without Cygwin](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1068998/Running-Apache-Kafka-on-Windows-without-Cygwin) 
[Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LS6WiHs_m5w)

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question. This question is answered here: 
[How to run following command to test kafka server is installed properly or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37064939/how-to-run-following-command-to-test-kafka-server-is-installed-properly-or-not/45467454#45467454)

Comment: Please note that coping and pasting the same answer to multiple questions is frowned upon.  If the same answer works without any modifications then you should be flagging/voting to close them as duplicates.

Comment: Yea, sorry I wasn't sure how to link this to the question I just answered! I can delete this answer and flag this question as a duplicate. I am just unsure how to flag the question as a duplicate.